# python module not found after pip installation

Tags: python, module, pip

Tried to install PythonQwt using pip, and also the recommended method below:

```sh
$ python3 -m pip install PythonQwt

Requirement already satisfied: PythonQwt in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.5.5)

Requirement already satisfied: NumPy>=1.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from PythonQwt) (1.17.2)
```

But I'm still getting this

```sh
$ python3

Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PythonQwt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PythonQwt'
```

already looked up different answers on stack overflow and tried them

Answer (score 2):

Though the package name is PythonQwt, you import it as just `qwt`. One [example](https://pythonhosted.org/PythonQwt/examples/index.html) from the official documentation is:

```
from qwt import tests
tests.run()
```

Comment: Oh wow, I missed that totally! Apologies for the silly error and thanks.I do get a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sip'", which i'm going to assume means i need to install sip as well for some reason

Comment: Hmmm, very strange : I did thhis $ python3 -m pip install sip and get 
Requirement already satisfied: sip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: toml in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sip) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sip) (19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in